# Delete all lines that start with comments and print statements from Python file

Tags: python

I want to delete all lines that start with comments and print statements from my file.

This code works on lines that don't start with indents:

```py
with open("in.py", "r") as file_input:
    with open("out.py", "w") as file_output: 
        for line in file_input:
            if line.startswith('#'):
                continue
            if line.startswith('print'):
                continue
            file_output.write(line)
```

But on lines that start with indents this does not work.

So this file_input:

```py
# comment 1
def foo():
    # comment 2
    x = 1
    print(x)
print(x)
```

returns this file_output:

```py
def foo():
    # comment 2
    x = 1
    print(x)
```

But I want it to return this:

```py
def foo():
    x = 1
```

How do you write this?

Comment: `if line.lstrip().startswith('#'):` and `if line.lstrip().startswith('print'):`

Comment: 10 seconds, fastest stack solution ever.  I would accept this answer if I could.  thanks

Comment: Just a note - deleting `print` statements may create syntax errors, e.g. `if something: print('foo')` becomes just `if something:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to strip leading whitespace or the line won't *start with* `'#'` or `'print'`. You can also combine the two conditions with `or`.

```
with open("in.py", "r") as file_input:
  with open("out.py", "w") as file_output: 
    for line in file_input:
      stripped = line.lstrip()
      if stripped.startswith('#') or stripped.startswith('print'):
        continue
      file_output.write(line)
```

We can also simplify by combining context managers.

```
with open("in.py", "r") as file_input, \
     open("out.py", "w") as file_output: 
  for line in file_input:
    stripped = line.lstrip()
    if stripped.startswith('#') or stripped.startswith('print'):
      continue
    file_output.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that you're ignoring whitespace. All you need to do is run `.lstrip()` to get rid of leading whitespace. Just do this:

```
with open("in.py", "r") as file_input:
    with open("out.py", "w") as file_output:
        for line in file_input:
            stripped = line.lstrip()
            if stripped.startswith('#') or stripped.startswith('print'):
                continue
            file_output.write(line)
```